# How to test Django's UpdateView?

Tags: python, django

As a simplified example, I've written an `UpdateView` for a `Book` model, as well as a `ListView` to redirect to upon success:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from .models import Book


class BookUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Book
    fields = ['title', 'author']


class BookList(ListView):
    model = Book
```

The `Book` model is defined as

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('books-list')
```

where `urls.py` is

```
from django.urls import path
from books.views import BookUpdate, BookList


urlpatterns = [
    path('books/', BookList.as_view(), name='books-list'),
    path('book/<int:pk>/', BookUpdate.as_view(), name='book-update')
]
```

In `books/tests.py` I've tried to write the following test:

```
class BookUpdateTest(TestCase):
    def test_update_book(self):
        book = Book.objects.create(title='The Catcher in the Rye')

        response = self.client.post(
            reverse('book-update', kwargs={'pk': book.id}), 
            {'author': 'J.D. Salinger'})

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        book.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertEqual(book.author, 'J.D. Salinger')
```

However, this test fails because the `book`'s `author` appears not to be updated after the `POST` request, even after refreshing from the database:

```
FAIL: test_update_book (books.tests.BookUpdateTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Scratch/book_project/books/tests.py", line 46, in test_update_book
    self.assertEqual(book.author, 'J.D. Salinger')
AssertionError: '' != 'J.D. Salinger'
+ J.D. Salinger
```

On the other hand, if I run the development server and fill out the fields manually, everything seems to work as expected. How can I write a unit test for the `UpdateView` which captures the user updating the fields, submitting the form, and making changes to the corresponding objects?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It seems that if you `POST` to a form, you have to post all required fields, not just the ones you are updating - even if the required field of the underlying model already has a value. Also, the status code returned upon a successful update is 302 'Found', not 200 'OK'. So the following test passes:

```
class BookUpdateTest(TestCase):
    def test_update_book(self):
        book = Book.objects.create(title='The Catcher in the Rye')

        response = self.client.post(
            reverse('book-update', kwargs={'pk': book.id}), 
            {'title': 'The Catcher in the Rye', 'author': 'J.D. Salinger'})

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

        book.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertEqual(book.author, 'J.D. Salinger')
```

Comment: Upvote is not enough : you deserve a thank comment in addition !

Answer (score 1):

In Django 3.2, you can find here the canonical solution:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/

In a test, you just need to:

- create the objects with the values included in the slug,
- and then, reverse it with these arguments:

```
 self.topic = Book.objects.create(slug="test-update")
        self.response = self.client.get(reverse('book_update', args=[self.topic.slug]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`TestCase` has `self.assertContains(response, el, html=True)`. `html= True` will render the `TemplateResponse` for you.