# Django tests AssertionError for update view

Tags: django, testing, django-views, assertion

I tried to create Django test for UpdateView

but I have such problem as:
self.assertEqual(application.credit_purpose, 'House Loan')
AssertionError: 'Car Loan' != 'House Loan'

- Car Loan

- House Loa

  ```
    def test_application_update(self):
    application = Application.objects.create(customer=self.customer, credit_amount=10000, credit_term=12,
                                                  credit_purpose='Car Loan', credit_pledge=self.pledge,
                                                  product=self.product,
                                                  number_request=2, date_posted='2020-01-01', reason='None',
                                                  repayment_source=self.repayment, possible_payment=1000,
                                                  date_refuse='2020-01-02', protokol_number='123457',
                                                  status=self.status,
                                                  language=0, day_of_payment=1, credit_user=self.user)

    response = self.client.post(
        reverse('application_update', kwargs={'pk': application.id}),
        {'credit_purpose': 'House Loan'})

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    application.refresh_from_db()
    self.assertEqual(application.credit_purpose, 'House Loan')
  ```

This is my model

```
class Application(AbstractCredit):
number_request = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Номер заявки', unique=True, default=number_auto)  # Добавить автоинкремент
date_posted = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата заявки', auto_now_add=True)
reason = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Причина отказа/Условия одобрения')
repayment_source = models.ForeignKey(Repayment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Источник погашения')
possible_payment = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Желаемая сумма ежемесячного взноса')
date_refuse = models.DateField(default=one_day_more, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Дата отказа/одобрения')
protokol_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, null=True, blank=True,
                                   verbose_name='Номер протокола')
status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1, verbose_name='Статус')
language = models.IntegerField(choices=LANGUAGES_CHOICES, verbose_name='Язык договора', blank=True, null=True)
day_of_payment = models.IntegerField(choices=DAY_OF_PAYMENT_CHOICES,
                                     verbose_name='Предпочитаемый день оплаты по кредиту')
credit_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET(0), verbose_name='Кредитный специалист')
```

This is my view

```
class ApplicationUpdate(BasePermissionMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
model = Application
form_class = ApplicationForm
template_name = 'standart_form.html'
permission_required = 'Изменение заявки'
success_message = 'Заявка успешно изменена'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['button_name'] = 'Сохранить'
    return context

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('application_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.get_object().id})
```

Comment: Could you share your `model` and `view` so we can easily replicate your problem?

Comment: I added model and view to my question

Answer (score 0):

So, I also got stuck in this for a while. The main problem is at:

```
    ...
    response = self.client.post(
        reverse('application_update', kwargs={'pk': application.id}),
        {'credit_purpose': 'House Loan'}
    )
    ...
```

I was able to understand thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48815002/7100120). It happens because you are posting to a `form` and it expects to have all fields filled, otherwise it will fail validation and thus will not call `.save()`.

What you can do is, after creating the `object` copy its data into a dictionary, then modify it before posting:

tests.py

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

class ApplicationTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        customer = Customer.objects.create(...)
        ...
        self.data = {
            'customer': customer, 'credit_amount': 10000, 'credit_term': 12,
            'credit_purpose': 'Car Loan', ...
        }

    def test_application_update(self):
        application = Application.objects.create(**self.data)

        post_data = model_to_dict(application)
        post_data['credit_purpose'] = 'House Loan'

        response = self.client.post(
            reverse(
                'app:view-name', kwargs={'pk': application.id}),
                post_data
        )

        # print(application.credit_purpose)
        # application.refresh_from_db()
        # print(application.credit_purpose)

        # It returns a redirect so code is 302 not 200.
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertEqual(application.credit_purpose, 'House Loan')
```

Also, [`get_absolute_url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#generic-editing-views) is set in the wrong place should be under models:

models.py

```
class Application(AbstractCredit):
    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('app:view-name', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```